# Simple calculation using script written in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, calc

I am really new to calculations in html/js. A colleague gave me a script written in Google Sheets and I am trying to implement it into a html calculator I have created. Here is a simple example (the full script will calculate many inputs when a button is cliked) of what I am trying to do:

**The html:**

```
<input type="text" id="A" value="2"> X
<input type="text" id="B" value="5">
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate"> = 
<output id="total"></output>
```

**Script:**

```
function calculate() {
    var A = document.getElementById("A").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("B").value;
    var total = A*B;
};
```

I know this is probably terribly wrong, but I am learning :)

[**Codepen example**](https://codepen.io/JonoGIS/pen/MBVeRX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't assigning the calculated value to the DOM.

Working Example:

```js
function calculate() {
    var A = document.getElementById("A").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("B").value;
    var total = A*B;

    document.getElementById("total").value = total;

};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="A" value="2"> X
<input type="text" id="B" value="5">
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate"> = 
<output id="total"></output>
```